# Using free monad to implement akka http dsl

Tags: scala, akka-http, scala-cats

I have been reading about free monad for a week. I want to implement Akka Http routing DSL with `free monads`.

I only have path and http method directives(post and get). In Akka Http, route is **RequestContext -> Future[RouteResult]**.

Here is my current external dsl for users.

```
route {
  path ("service-a") {
    get
  },
  path ("service-b) {
    get
  },
  path ("service-c) {
    get,
    post
  }
}
```

You can think that this is a http proxy service. For `service-a`, only get method is available, and for `service-c`, get and post.

After user defined this, I will use this defination in my internal code.

In my internal communication, I have a service for `Request to Response`. Basically, response logic is"

```
for {
  services <- route
  service <- services(httprequest.path)
  availableMethods <- service
  response <- httpresponse if availableMethods(httprequest.method)
} yield response
```

How can i achieve this with free monad? As well as I understand, I need to have two `interpreter`, one is for users(external dsl), other is for internal dsl?

What about the performance with this solution. In Akka Http, route is just a function from `ReqeustContext to result`. What about implementation with free monad?

Comment: You may want to check this out http://frees.io/docs/integrations/akkahttp/